# Склонение названий населенных пунктов

Tags: склонение

Как правильно написать проживает в городе Киржач или проживает в городе Киржаче.

А если пишем проживает в г. Александров или г. Александрове.

Поясните как склоняются названия поселков, деревень, сел.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: в городе Киржаче.
Город - это родовое наименование топонима "Воронеж" (приложение перед именем собственным), а русские топонимы при наличии родового наименования склоняются: в городе Москве, на острове Валааме. Это основная форма.

Топоним может не склоняться только в некоторых частных случаях, когда действуют особые правила. Это названия на ОВО/ЁВО/ЕВО и ИНО/ЫНО (у села Бородино, в усадьбе Абрамцево, также: в городе Великие Луки (но: в Великих Луках), у Медведь-горы (но по Москве-реке).

Вариант "в городе Киржач" возможен только в профессиональной речи топографов с целью сохранения точности названия.

Answer (score 0):

Название города склоняется вместе с родовым словом.